# Django - changes in url after facebook login redirect

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, facebook-login, django-1.4

I'm doing a server-side login into facebook, after successful login a user is redirected to the right place and everything, but the url has a number of special signs at the end.

Here is my login function:

```
def fb_login(request):
    args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri())

    # the user is already logged into facebook
    if 'code' in request.GET:
        args['client_secret'] = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
        args['code'] = request.GET.get('code')
        response = urlparse.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook"
                                                ".com/oauth/access_token?" +
                                               urllib.urlencode(args)).read())
        # A short lived access token
        access_token = response['access_token'][0]

        # Extending the short lived access token
        args['grant_type'] = "fb_exchange_token"
        args['fb_exchange_token'] = access_token
        reponse2 = urlparse.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook"
                                                ".com/oauth/access_token?" +
                                               urllib.urlencode(args)).read())

        token = Token.objects.create(token=reponse2['access_token'][0],
            expires_in=int(reponse2['expires'][0]))
        # do stuff with the token
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))

    # the user is not logged into facebook yet
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" +
                                    urllib.urlencode(args))
```

Instead of this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/profile/
```

I get this:

```
http://localhost:8000/profile/#_=_
```

What can cause the url to change like this?

Comment: The login flow appends this hash to the current address, for some security reasons.

Comment: @CBroe Hmmm..interesting. It doesn't happen after twitter login. Should i be worried about it? Seems like it doesn't affect anything, all other links on the page work properly.